# CSS arrow moving up and down when making the screen smaller

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently learning how to make a website, however my CSS arrow is perfect on full screen but when I reduce the screen width it keeps moving up and down. I will attach link to my website and also the CSS code for my arrow. 
I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. 
Thank you !
Please open the website on full screen as it is not fully responsive yet.
Link to the website - http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~icham002/web/index.html

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow-down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 49%;
  margin-left: 48%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down" onclick="slideDown()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because % in margin is related to width and whenever you change size of the screen you decrease the width and thus you decrease the margin. Instead you can use the top/left property to position your element where you want.

And it's better to apply this property the parent element instead of the pseudo element:

```css
.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 49%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.arrow-down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down" onclick="slideDown()"></div>
```

Comment: The arrow is not moving when i make the screen smaller, however it stays on the top of my page and even if I change the top it is not going further down..

Comment: @IvanC you removed the other style like i did ?

Comment: I have copied the code you did here and paste it, however the arrow stays in the middle at the top of my page and it doesn't move further down even if I change the top

Comment: @IvanC is the code on your site right now ? so i can see

Comment: yes i just uploaded it, you can open it and see.. 
http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~icham002/web/index.html also when I open my website from my phone i can see the website as from a laptop it is not getting smaller and also the main background with the snow is not loading ..

Comment: @IvanC i adjusted my code :) it's because of the parent element and now you can adjust the top like you want ;)

Comment: Perfect it is now working ! Thank you very much!! Can I ask you, why my main background is not loading on my phone? Also when I reduce the size of my browser on my laptop the website is getting smaller adjusted , but when I open the website from my phone it is as it is when I open it from my laptop on full screen ?

Comment: @IvanC you need to add this to your HTML code : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and may learn more about here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're including some CSS that's not necessary in your snippet. This can be reduced.

What I've done here is made it so the positioning of the arrow is being done using the `bottom` and `left` properties. It's centered using `translateX(-50%)`. This should work now on different sized screens.

A working example can be seen here:

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.arrow-down::after {
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-50%);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-50%);
    animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down" onclick="slideDown()"></div>
```

Comment: The arrow is not moving when i make the screen smaller, however it stays on the top of my page and even if I change the top it is not going further down..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean but the positioning is being set using `bottom: 10%;`, so you should be able to move it up and down the page by changing this value.

Comment: when i change the bottom the arrow doesn't move at all any further up or down it stays in the middle of the screen at the top of my page

Comment: Right, I've updated my working example and I think I know you mean now.

Comment: It is not moving now when i make the page smaller which is good, however it is a bit after my main page, it's where the title about me is..

Comment: That's good, I've just updated the snippet again. Now you should be able to adjust the position using just the `bottom` on `.arrow-down`.

Comment: It's sorted! Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

Try to specify values in px instead of % for

```
margin-top: 49%;
margin-left: 48%;
```